# What does「十分になるか、ならないか」mean?

Tags: grammar

Currently reading こころ 四話

> 「たった今出たばかりで、**十分になるか、ならないかでございます**」と奥さんは気の毒そうにいってくれた。

Does the bold part mean the same thing as「十分になるかもしれません」? How this phrase works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of 十分になるかもしれません *Possibly ten mins have passed* may be not that different from the bold phrase, but it is more interchangeable with 十分くらいです *It is about ten mins*.

Generally Xになるかならないか where X contains some quantity means *(the amount) reaches X or possibly less*. In the example, the amount is the time that has passed since someone (husband?) left home, and she is saying it is 10±α mins.

Some other examples:

- 私が10歳になるかならないかのとき *When I was around 10 years old*
- このパソコンは5万するかしないかだった *This PC costed 50000 yen or maybe less*
- 今年のボーナスは100万いくかいかないかくらいだ *This year's bonus will be around 1000000 yen*

The pattern has a nuance of *at most (around) X*, which should be the difference from the other expressions mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

After Chocolate explained it to me, I'll try and give a better answer.

The bolded part is still an embedded question. The quoted sentence means:

> It just came out. It will be about 10 minutes.

Here, using かもしれません changes the meaning quite drastically: it now means "It might be ten minutes".

Edit: in response to Nanigashi's comment, the quoted sentence would mean:

> He just left, about 10 minutes ago.